# Round to nearest even value based on row by row conditions using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to round EACH VALUE to the nearest even number, with this logic:
Any value less than or = to 0.69, round down to 0

```
**Data**
                    
Location    range     type  Q1 28   Q2 28   Q3 28   Q4 28   rounded_sum
NY          low re    AA    1.14    0       0       0       2
NY          low re    BB    0       0       0       0       0
NY          low re    DD    0.51    2       4       0       6
NY          low re    SS    0       0       0       0       0
NY          low stat  AA    1.03    2       2       4       10
NY          low stat  BB    0.45    0       2       2       4
NY          low stat  DD    1.53    2       4       6       14
NY          low stat  SS    0.26    0       0       2       2
CA          low re    AA    0.34    0       2       0       2
CA          low re    BB    0       0       0       0       0
CA          low re    DD    0.69    0       2       0       2
CA          low re    SS    0       0       0       0       0
CA          low stat  AA    0.18    0       0       2       2
CA          low stat  BB    0.2     0       0       0       0
CA          low stat  DD    0.27    0       0       2       2
CA          low stat  SS    0.04    0       0       0       0


**Desired**

Location    range     type  Q1 28   Q2 28   Q3 28   Q4 28   rounded_sum
NY          low re    AA    2       0       0       0       2
NY          low re    BB    0       0       0       0       0
NY          low re    DD    0       2       4       0       6
NY          low re    SS    0       0       0       0       0
NY          low stat  AA    2       2       2       4       10
NY          low stat  BB    0       0       2       2       4
NY          low stat  DD    2       2       4       6       14
NY          low stat  SS    0       0       0       2       2
CA          low re    AA    0       0       2       0       2
CA          low re    BB    0       0       0       0       0
CA          low re    DD    0       0       2       0       2
CA          low re    SS    0       0       0       0       0
CA          low stat  AA    0       0       0       2       2
CA          low stat  BB    0       0       0       0       0
CA          low stat  DD    0       0       0       2       2
CA          low stat  SS    0       0       0       0       0
```

**Doing**

```
arr1 = df.iloc[:, 3:].values
s1 = np.sum(arr1, axis=1)
s1 = np.where(s1 < 0.69, 0, np.ceil(s1 / 2) * 2)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 'applymap()' function

```
def round_to_even(x):
    if x <= 0.69:
        return 0
    else:
        return int(np.ceil(x / 2) * 2)

# Apply the rounding function to the relevant columns (Q1 28, Q2 28, Q3 28, Q4 28)
df.iloc[:, 3:7] = df.iloc[:, 3:7].applymap(round_to_even)

# Recalculate the rounded_sum
df['rounded_sum'] = df.iloc[:, 3:7].sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could help.

```
import pandas as pd
import math

def roundUpToEven(number):
    return math.ceil(number / 2) * 2

df['Q1 28'] = df['Q1 28'].apply(lambda x: 0 if (x<=0.69) else roundUpToEven(x))
print(df)
```

Edit:

In case you want to apply to multiple columns of your choice:

```
def roundUpToEven(number):
    return math.ceil(number / 2) * 2

def applyToSlice(slice):
     for column in slice:
          df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda x: 0 if (x <= 0.69) else roundUpToEven(x))

applyToSlice(df.iloc[:, 3:-1])
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you! Wondering does this only affect the values under Q1 28, since this is the only column called out? @Galo Torres Sevilla

Comment: Correct, only 'Q1 28' is selected, if you want to change for other columns you could use the same logic in a method and pass the Series as the argument